# Newrelic does not display CPU & memory usage for Docker's container

Tags: linux, docker, newrelic, centos7

I try to install New Relic Servers for Linux in my local vagrant machine running CentOS 7.2.1 with Docker 1.11.0 installed. I have follow the step to enable Servers for Linux for Docker, all running containers are shown in New Relic Server page but CPU & memory usage are empty. I also follow the guide to enable memory usage metrics but still no luck (https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/servers/new-relic-servers-linux/installation-configuration/enabling-new-relic-servers-docker#enable-memory-usage).

[image]

Am I missing something? Any clue on why it's not working?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, running Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have manage to get the help from New Relic Support Engineer. They found that Docker 1.10+ is not compatible with LSM.

Temparory workaround:

1. Open the file `/etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg`
2. Add the line `cgroup_style=0`
3. Save the file, and then restart LSM:

   `sudo /etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond restart`

Wait a few minutes, you will see Docker metrics are being reported.

> But bear in mind that it's an undocumented and untested workaround.

Discussion link:
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/wrong-path-to-cpu-and-memoy-data/36177

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm this also works for RHEL 7.2 (Maipo) on Amazon EC2

Comment: Confirmed for Ubuntu 14.04